# OpenGL created window size twice as large

Tags: macos, opengl, retina

I'm running learn OpenGL tutorials on a Macbook Pro 2015. The generated window dimension is twice as large as set. (e.g., set as 800x600 in the code, but got 1600x1200). And the triangle the code tries to draw is in lower left quadrant, when it's supposed to be in the center.

What might be the reason for this?

I ran this [code](http://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle2) and didn't make any change.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW1K2.png) to the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GLFW [FAQ](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html):

> 4.3 - Why is my output in the lower-left corner of the window?
>
> You are passing the window size, which is in screen coordinates, to
>   glViewport, which works with pixels. On OS X with a Retina display,
>   and possibly on other platforms in the future, screen coordinates and
>   pixels do not map 1:1. Use the framebuffer size, which is in pixels,
>   instead of the window size. See the Window handling guide for details.